# Tap Gesture Recognizer in uitableview cell Montouch

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using `UITapGestureRecognizer` for `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell`. Its showing for all cell but when I trying to tap the Image its getting crash. Can't figure out the solution. I mentioned the code below.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
string cellName = "Cell";
UITableViewCell cell;
cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("cellIdentifier");
if (cell == null) {
    cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
    UIImageView toCheckboximage;
    toCheckboximage = new UIImageView (new RectangleF (20, 10, 20, 20)); 
    toCheckboximage.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    toCheckboximage.Tag = 1;
    cell.ContentView.AddSubview (toCheckboximage);
}
UIView toCheckImgV = (UIImageView)cell.ContentView.ViewWithTag (1);
cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

tapRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer ();
toCheckImgV.AddGestureRecognizer (tapRecognizer);
tapRecognizer.AddTarget (() => {
    Console.WriteLine("coming");
});
  return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
   in Log i got the below error

```
Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at CyramedX.UI.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00016] in /Users/qatalys/Desktop/monotouch/Jun_24_2013/CyramedX/CyramedX.UI/Main.cs:21
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

    0   CyramedXUI                          0x0007cc9c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
    1   CyramedXUI                          0x00004fe8 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x970308cb _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   UIKit                               0x014d499b -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 333
    5   UIKit                               0x014d60df -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 46
    6   UIKit                               0x014d8d2d ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0543 + 57
    7   UIKit                               0x014d8cac _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 331
    8   UIKit                               0x014d0a28 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 1348
    9   UIKit                               0x0123d972 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1283
    10  UIKit                               0x0123de53 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 98
    11  UIKit                               0x0121bd4a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    12  UIKit                               0x0120d698 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x04a58df9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x04a58ad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x03e21bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x03e21962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x03e52bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x03e51f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x03e51e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x04a577e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x04a57668 GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x0120affc UIApplicationMain + 1211
    23  ???                                 0x0ed8effd 0x0 + 249098237
    24  ???                                 0x0ed8cea0 0x0 + 249089696
    25  ???                                 0x0ed8c4cc 0x0 + 249087180
    26  ???                                 0x0ed8c636 0x0 + 249087542
    27  CyramedXUI                          0x00009212 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
    28  CyramedXUI                          0x00150bee mono_runtime_invoke + 126
    29  CyramedXUI                          0x00154d14 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
    30  CyramedXUI                          0x00159845 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
    31  CyramedXUI                          0x00065ea5 mono_jit_exec + 149
    32  CyramedXUI                          0x001dd094 main + 1988
    33  CyramedXUI                          0x00002b55 start + 53

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue that on any `GetCell` call new `UITapGestureRecognizer` is creating and adding one more target. Move that block into `if` statement to run it once when `UITableViewCell` is creating.

Moreover, I recommend you to create `UIImageView` subclass with tap event functionality (with `UITapGestureRecognizer`) to avoid adding it in any place you need that event.

Please add `Application Log` data from `Xamarin Studio`'s console. Without that information it's difficult to understand where is exact problem.

Comment: Fix adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` on any `GetCell` call, then try again.

Comment: sorry,I didn't get you can you please tell me in detail

Comment: I tried all possibilities call the method from the GetCell to add button but nothing helps me

Comment: Make `UIImageView` subclass with tap functionality. Then use that component in your cell. Possibly, wrong target is used for gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Your crash could be caused by not keeping a reference to

UIImageView toCheckboximage;

or

UIView toCheckImgV

You should create a UITableViewCell subclass and add your UIImageView as a property to that class so you keep a reference in C#

Comment: I set the reference in public while tableview class begins